# RXJava handling nested calls

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

Imagine I have a service to retrieve some authors (id, firstname, lastname, birthday, nationality) and a second service to retrieve an author's book (title, summary, number of pages).
I would like my network call to return me a list of authors with their books.

To illustrate, my services would return me AuthorOResponse and BookResponse and I would like to emit an Observable of AuthorObject.

```
public class AuthorResponse {
    private String id;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private Date birthday;
    private String nationality;
}

public class BookResponse {
    private String title;
    private String summary;
    private int pageNumber;
}

public class AuthorObject {
    private String id;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private Date birthday;
    private String nationality;
    private List<BookObject> books
}
```

My services would be something like

```
Observable<List<AuthorResponse>> getAuthors()
Observable<List<BookResponse>> getAuthorBooks(String authorId)
```

I would like to use them to emit an Observable but cannot figure out how to do it since each of my calls to getAuthorBooks need an author.

I came up with something looking like this but I have an issue since my concatMap make me "loose" my author.

```
myServices.getAuthors()
                .map(author -> createAuthor())
                .concatMap(author -> mWebService.getAuthorBooks(author.getId())
                .flatMapIterable(data -> data.items)
                .map(book -> addBook())
```

Does someone know how I could do this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [special `flatMap` overload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41786439/retrofit-and-rxjava-how-to-combine-two-requests-and-get-access-to-both-results/41820372#41820372) designed for such cases:

```
myServices.getAuthors()
    .map(author -> createAuthor())
    .flatMap(author -> mWebService.getAuthorBooks(author.getId()),
            (author, data) -> {
                author.setBooks(data.items));
                return Observable.just(author);
            })
    .toList() //here is your Observable<List<Author>>
```

Comment: That seems really great.
Since I want to emit an Observable<AuthorObject> I will have the flatMap return my author but it work well.
Thank !

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

```
getAuthors.map(new Func1<List<AuthorResponse>, AuthorObject>() {
        @Override
        public AuthorObject call(List<AuthorResponse> authorResponses) {
            return createAuthor();
        }
    }).flatMap(new Func1<AuthorObject, Observable<AuthorObject>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<AuthorObject> call(final AuthorObject authorObject) {
            return getAuthorBooks(authorObject.id)
                    .map(new Func1<List<BookResponse>, AuthorObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public AuthorObject call(List<BookResponse> bookResponses) {
                            authorObject.books = parseBooks(bookResponses);
                            return authorObject;
                        }
                    });
        }
    });
```

Query the Authors, map each `AuthorResponse` to `AuthorObject`, then using `flatMap` query books for each `Author`, and `map` it in order to add parsed books to the generated earlier `AuthorObject`.
at the end you'll get an `Observable` that emits `AuthorObject` with their books list populated.