# prepare map using Observable Rx-java

Tags: java, rx-java, couchbase, couchbase-java-api

Here i my sample code which returns list of `JsonDocument` from couchbase server.

```
Cluster cluster = CouchbaseCluster.create();
Bucket bucket = cluster.openBucket();

List<JsonDocument> foundDocs = Observable
    .just("key1", "key2", "key3", "key4", "key5")
    .flatMap(new Func1<String, Observable<JsonDocument>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<JsonDocument> call(String id) {
            return bucket.async().get(id);
        }
    })
    .toList()
    .toBlocking()
    .single();
```

I want to return `Map` instead of `List`.My return type would be `Map<String, JsonDocument>`.
I tried with `toMap` method but it did not work for me.

Comment: Please provide the code you tried and what result you got.

Comment: Is your problem to combine key and flatMap result? Then check this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/41820372/7045114

Answer (score 0):

You correctly mentioned in your comment that `toMap` needs a `Function` as its argument. This `Function` will be used to "extract" (or maybe "construct") the key under which each value will be entered into the map.

So, in your case you will need a `Function<JsonDocument, String>` that takes a `JsonDocument` as its input and somehow returns a `String` which you will later use to find the `JsonDocument` in the `Map`. What that `String` will be is something only you can answer - maybe there is some ID inside the `JsonDocument`?