# 2 dependent retrofit requests made by RxJava

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, foursquare, rx-java2

I'm using the foursquare API to retrieve photos of nearby venues and display them.
I'm doing it by RxJava and Retrofit.
The first time I need to request a list of venues with proper ids and the second request should be with ids as parameters to retrieve photos for every single venue.
I wanna do everything with single RxJava call because that's the best practice, isn't it?
Below is my code, unfortunately, I stuck at the place when I should do the second request. Any hint how should I solve it?

```
        Observable<VenuesResponse> observable = mApiService.getVenues();

    observable
            .map(new Function<VenuesResponse, List<VenuesItem>>() {
                @Override
                public List<VenuesItem> apply(VenuesResponse venuesResponse) throws Exception {
                    return venuesResponse.getResponse().getVenues();
                }
            })
            .flatMap(new Function<List<VenuesItem>, ObservableSource<VenuesItem>>() {
                @Override
                public ObservableSource<VenuesItem> apply(List<VenuesItem> venuesItems) throws Exception {
                    return Observable.fromIterable(venuesItems);
                }
            })

            //TODO code that requests for photo and adds url to VenuesItem

            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe();
}
```

Comment: So, the second call should use `VenuesItem::getId()` as parameter for the call?

Comment: yes. BTW I discovered another API that returns photos in the first response, but I'm still curious how to solve it!

Comment: It can be solved by this operator - http://stackoverflow.com/a/41820372/7045114