# Preserve an argument after a series of concat operators RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

Is it possible to access the first argument of the operators down the line? I'm trying to preserve the value using the zip operator but I haven't managed to do it. Thanks for the help

```
.concatMap(this::getDeviceStatus)
                .concatMap(this::getCertificateResponse)
                .concatMap(deviceCertificateResponse ->
                        CertificateGenerator.generateCert(deviceCertificateResponse))
                .concatMap(aBoolean -> CrlGenerator.observableCrlGenerator(aBoolean,getCertificateResponse ))  // <- I want to use the first argument again in the last concat map
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could preserve your upstream argument via nesting:

```
Observable.just("initialValue")
    .concatMap(initialValue -> {
        someMethod(initialValue)
            .concatMap(transformedValue -> anotherMethod(initialValue, transformedValue))
    });
```

Also, when using `Observables` and `flatMaps`, nesting could be replaced with [flatMap overload with result selector](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41820372/7045114).

Comment: Thanks, plain and simple