# RxJava - Combine 2 calls

Tags: java, rx-java

I have 2 Observables, which call 2 WS

1. Get a list of cars (at this point, each car from this list doesn't have his owner)
2. Get the owner of the car

So first I get the list of cars. Everything is ok. But I would to get the owner for each car and set it in the Car entity, like `car.setOwner(owner)` and send the final list of cars, containing their owner.

```
Api.getCars()
.subscribe(new Action1<List<Car>>() {
    @Override
    public void call(List<Car> cars) {
    // get the list of cars, but need to get their owner
    });
```

Which is the best way to do this? (Moreover, without lambdas.)

Comment: what does it matter if it is with lambda or not?

Comment: Because for now, the project doesn't use them

Comment: @ejay `getting the owner` is another async api call right?

Comment: So you should get owner of each car in `call(List<Car> cars)`, what is the problem?

Comment: @Manza right ;)

Comment: @syntagma, yes, but how should I do that in the best way? Just a for loop and get sync call until I finished, a zip of the 2 observables...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could utilize [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41820372/7045114) `flatMap` overload:

```
Api.getCars()
    .flatMap(cars -> Observable.from(cars)) // flatten your list
    .flatmap(car -> Api.getOwner(car), // request each owner
            (car, owner) -> {
                car.setOwner(owner); // assign owner to the car
                return Observable.just(car);
            })
    .toList() // collect items into List
    ... // here is your Observable<List<Car>>
```