# rxJava how to make sequential call while being able to acess previous parameter

Tags: rx-java, rx-java3

### This is the flow I need to follow to create a file record in my server

Black arrow is flow
Red arrow is dependency
This is one big function
[image]

### I need help designing this in rxjava that make them happen sequentially while the later single is  able to get the reference

I can create some single for each time taking task

```java
public static Single<byte[]> processData(byte[] fileData))
public static Single<APIResponse> callAPI(String id, byte[] processedData)
public static Single<UploadResponse> uploadData(String url)
```

This is my attempt
I tried using flatMap's resultSelector as described here
[Retrofit and RxJava: How to combine two requests and get access to both results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41786439/retrofit-and-rxjava-how-to-combine-two-requests-and-get-access-to-both-results)

```java
    private static Single<FinalResult> bigFunction(String id, int type, String jwt, byte[] fileData){

        return processData(fileData).flatMap(new Function<byte[], SingleSource<APIResponse>>() {
            @Override
            public SingleSource<APIResponse> apply(byte[] processedData) throws Throwable {
                return callAPI(id, processedData);
            }
        }, new BiFunction<byte[], APIResponse, UploadResponse>() {
            @Override
            public FinalResult apply(byte[] processData, APIResponse apiResponse) throws Throwable {
                if (processData.size() > LIMIT){
                    uploadData(apiResponse.getUrl());  // I am stuck here how to return a FinalResult() after this uploadData() is complete
                }else{
                   return new FinalResult(); // if no need to upload, done
                }
                
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need a result then you can [`ignoreElement()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Single.html#ignoreElement--) to convert your flow into `Completable` and use [`toSingleDefault(...)`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Completable.html#toSingleDefault-T-) function:

```
uploadData(apiResponse.getUrl())
    .ignoreElement()
    .toSingleDefault(new FinalResult());
```

In case you just need to convert the response into `FinalResult` then you can use `map(...)`:

```
uploadData(apiResponse.getUrl())
     .map(uploadResponse -> new FinalResult(uploadResponse));
```

In case you have to utilize the result from `uploadData(..)` with any external calls or whatever then `flatMap()` is your choice:

```
uploadData(apiResponse.getUrl())
    .flatMap(uploadResponse -> {
        // do whatever you want with response
        return Single.just(new FinalResult(uploadResponse));
    });
```

**UPDATE:**

In your case it can be simplified:

```
return processData(fileData)
    .flatMap(processedData -> {
        Single<FinalResult> postProcessing;
        if (processedData.length > LIMIT) {
            postProcessing = uploadData(apiResponse.getUrl())
                                .map(response -> new FinalResult(response));
        } else {
            postProcessing = Single.just(new FinalResult());
        }
        return callAPI(id, processedData)
            .ignoreElement()
            .andThen(postProcessing);
            
    });
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I choose the second map approach, but I think calling the map on Single return another single. So it actually reutrn a Single<FinalResult> inside BiFunction

Comment: Hey, I posted an update. Does it look like working solution now?